# SQL question - Find the name of those who have children of both genders

Tags: mysql, sql

So during an interview I was asked this question and completely blanked out

I was provided with this table, and had to find the names of parents who at least one male and one female child

| Parent Name | Child Gender |
| --- | --- |
| Alyssa | F |
| Alyssa | M |
| Ben | F |
| Cathy | M |
| Cathy | M |

So the output should just be Alyssa

Answer (score 1):

If only M/F is in the `Child_Gender` column, then the simplest statistical method

```
 SELECT
    parent_name, COUNT(DISTINCT Child_Gender) AS num
  FROM
    users
 GROUP BY parent_name 
 HAVING num > 1
```

Comment: Someone (includes the one asking question) might ask "what `COUNT(DISTINCT` do?" or "why I need to use `HAVING`? can I just use `WHERE`?". So, it's better to give a brief explanation on how the query works.

Comment: @FanoFN
1. Distinct function: Since you require both M & F, it is possible to have multiple members of the same gender without duplexing, which does not meet the requirement.


2. `Group by` is the result set. Only having can be used for filtering

Comment: What FanoFN is telling you politely is to explain your answer,  That is how you are supposed to answer  It doesn't mean that he doesn't understand it :-)